# div width relative to content

Tags: jquery, html, automation, width

Is there a way to dynamically set a div width / make the width relative to the content - using jQuery? It has to be with a numerical value because otherwise, it doesn't work with the horizontal website layout I'm dealing with...

The div will only contains images with a defined width values.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution I was looking for :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var width = 0;
$('#page img').each(function() {
    width += $(this).outerWidth( true );
});
$('#page').css('width', width + 0);
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

a `div` will stretch to fit its container (however wide it may be) by default if it doesn't have a `width` explicitly set.

set the `div` to have `display:inline-block;` and it will stretch to fit its contents, which is what you seem to want.

see example here: http://jsbin.com/usuno4

Answer (score 1):

Div widths are 100% of the containing element, unless you have styles affecting the div or the div is inside a inline element.

--

Can you give any more information on what exactly you're trying to accomplish. The question is a quick answer, but I believe you're looking for more.

Comment: If it can helps, I'm rebuilding http://www.joliannelm.com/europe.html and I need a different width value on my div according to the images in it. Since I'm rebuilding the site in a CMS and I want to make it very easy for my client to edit it, I don't want to have a custom value to enter on each page.

Comment: And I must use a value in px, otherwise, I can't have the horizontal scrolling in the browser...